# How to Count data between two relation in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to count data from the table, I have a relation between 2 tables and I want to display records after the count in the Django template, Please let me know how I can display count values in Django.

here is my `models.py file...

```
class TestForm(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)

class TestForm2(models.Model):
    name1=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    customer_data=models.ForeignKey(TestForm, related_name='GetRelatedname', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='TestForm')
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def myview(request, id):
   datas=TestForm.objects.all)
   template_name='test.html'
   context={'datas':datas}
   return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my Html file code.

```
{% for a in datas.GetRelatedname.all %}
 {{a.customer_data.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

but its counting nothing and I want to count `customer_data`

Comment: You are doing it correct unless you did something wrong on models. So, you've got to show models.py.

Comment: Please share the model and view. Normally you do not write (complicated) queries in a template, since this is business logic and belongs in the view.

Comment: Please check my updates question

Comment: The two models have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Do the logic part in the view, what is the point of using MVC otherwise? Like so:

```
def myview(request, id):
    datas=TestForm.objects.select_related("customer_data").all()
    template_name='test.html'
    context={'datas':datas}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

And `customer_data` is a foreign key, you can't count a foreign key. One instance of `TestForm` will only have one `customer_data`. And make the model names different.